# grouping of skewed dara

Tags: data-analysis

I have a set of data composed of the measurements of spaces. There are 2 distinct sizes represented in this data set. 
(distinct in that the larger size is larger by some unknown multiple)
I am looking for away to separate the items such that the larger items are in there own set.

data samples
 2  3  4  4  4  5  7  8  10  10  13  15

separate between 8  & 10

2  3  3  4  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  6  6  6  6  6  8  15  17  18

separate between 8 & 15

1  1  1  1  1  1  3  3  3  3  3  4  4  4  5  5  7  9  12  14

separate between 5 & 7

if I look at the actual objects the "separate between" would separate the two groups

(some background : the smaller sizes are the space between letters in a word and the larger are the space between words in a sentence)